# wrote a program for printing the prime numbers not getting the desired output .where i am going wrong?

Tags: c

not able to get the desired output,help to find my error.I know that I made it complex,but this is implementation of instinct thought from  beginner.
For suppose if I give a input value 5 the output value showing is 3,4,6,8,12
where actual output should be 2,3,5,7,11.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int count,n,counte=0,j=2,i;
    printf("enter a number of prime numbers to print:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(counte=1;counte<=n;)//for no.of prime numbers to be printed
    {
        while(j<=(j+1))
        {
            count=0;
            for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
            {
                if((j%i)==0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }


            if(count==2)

            {
                printf("%d \n",j);
                counte++;
                j++;
                break;
            }
             j++;
           }
         }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to solve the problem methodically, step by step, instead of by instinct though. You'll avoid writing things that don't make much sense like `while(j<=(j+1))`.

Comment: It is more usual to place the `counte++` within the `for` conditions, rather than leaving that blank and placing it somewhere in the `for` code block. Better to rethink the logic.

Comment: I don't understand why you are testing if `j` is divisible by `1`.

Comment: prime number should be divisible by 1 and itself so for that the count will be only 2 for prime numbers and for all remaining numbers count will be more than 2.

Comment: @SreeHarsha **every** natural number is divisible by 1 and itself. Why waste time checking?

Comment: i am bothered,why this code is not working, not about efficient way of writing at this point of time.

Comment: Have you dealt with the very first comment?

Comment: yes seen that. just for trying i took j<=20 and tried same output.I wrote that because  I don't know till what number we have to check to get the desired no.of prime numbers that depends on the input value .

Comment: this line: `while(j<=(j+1))` will never exit the while loop.  If that is what you want, suggest: `while(1)`    when calling scanf() and family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameters) to assure the operation was successful.  for readability//understandability by us humans, only declare one variable per statement.   the header file: `conio.h` is not portable.  strongly suggest elimination of that statement and use the standard C library functions, like `getchar()` rather than `getch()`  etc

Comment: when writing code like: `if(count==2)` always place the literal on the left, so the compiler will catch an error like: `if(2 = count)` when it should have been: `if( 2 == count )`

Comment: please indent consistently.  do not use tabs for indenting as each editor/wordprocessor has the tab stops/tab widths set differently.  suggest indenting 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible, even with variable width fonts.  Suggest indenting after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Answer (score 0):

the following code:

```
compiles cleanly
performs the desired operation
checks for errors
is consistently indented


#include <stdio.h>
//#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int count;
    int n;
    int counte=0;
    int j=2; // number to test to see if it is prime
    int i;

    printf("enter a number of prime numbers to print:");
    if( 1 != scanf("%d",&n) )
    { // then scanf failed
        perror( "scanf failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    if( 0 > n )
    {
        printf( "positive counts only\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, num primes to print is positive

    for(counte=0, j=2; counte<n; j++)//for no.of prime numbers to be printed
    {
        count=0;

        for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
        {
            if((j%i)==0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }


        if(2 == count)
        {
            printf("%d \n",j);
            counte++;
        }
    } // end for

    getchar(); // gets leftover newline
    getchar(); // waits for user to hit a key
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, your code is nice.even my code is working haven't changed any thing even while(j<=(j+1)) is working fine. actually running my code in dev c++ ,by mistake I saved the file with .cpp extensionin in this  for  5 as input ,output showing is 3,4,6,8,12(which is +1 of every prime number).when i realised that and now saved with .c extension the same code is working fine.thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `j` as the prime number variable, so the problem is that your are making an incremental operation for `j` before printing. The correct example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int count,n,counte=0,j=2,i;
    printf("enter a number of prime numbers to print:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(counte=1;counte<=n;)//for no.of prime numbers to be printed
    {
        while(j<=(j+1))
        {
            count=0;
            for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
            {
                if((j%i)==0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            // Here was incremental.

            if(count==2)

            {
                printf("%d \n",j);
                counte++;

                break;
            }

            j++; //Here is now.


        }
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code will print 2 n times. The `if(count==2)` is true on the first loop, so the j++ is never reached, and it will still be true on the following loops.

Comment: i have placed j++ inside and outside the loop and tried same output.